# Angular.js Scope Primitive Values- Shorten function?

Tags: angularjs

I have primitive values on my scope and I was wondering if there was a better way to handle these values and shorten my function which seems bloated.

```
angular.module('main.loadbalancer').controller('CreateNodeCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, LoadBalancerService, StatusTrackerService, NodeService) {
  $scope.createNode = function(node) {
    var TIME_CLOSE_MODAL;
    TIME_CLOSE_MODAL = 3000;
    $scope.disableButtonsForRun = false;
    $scope.statusBar = true;
    $scope.nodeStatus = 'Building';
    $scope.statusType = 'warning';
    return LoadBalancerService.getLoadBalancer().then(function(loadBalancer) {
      return NodeService.createNode({
        account_number: loadBalancer.customer,
        admin_state: 'enabled',
        label: node.label,
        ip: node.ip,
        port: node.port,
        comment: node.comment,
        health_strategy: {},
        vendor_extensions: {}
      }).then(function(eventId) {
        trackStatus = void 0;
        $scope.disableButtonsForRun = true;
        StatusTrackerService.runEventCheck(loadBalancer.customer, eventId)
        .then(function() {
          $scope.statusType = 'success';
          $scope.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';
          setTimeout((function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
          }), TIME_CLOSE_MODAL);
        }, function() {
          $scope.nodeStatus = 'Failure!';
          $scope.statusType = 'danger';
        })['finally'](function() {
          $scope.disableButtonsForRun = false;
        });
      });
    });
  };
  $scope.node = {
    keepaliveType: 'TCP',
    keepaliveMethod: 'GET'
  };
  $scope.close = function() {
    $scope.nodeStatus = 'Building';
    $scope.statusType = 'warning';
    $modalInstance.close();
  };});
```

---

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div ng-if="statusBar">
    <div class="row">
      <progressbar animate="false" class="progress-striped active"  value="100" type="{{statusType}}">{{nodeStatus}}</progressbar>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch on="disableButtonsForRun">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-disabled="true" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createNode($parent.node)" ng-disabled="true">Create</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createNode($parent.node)" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || !form.$dirty">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I was told that when placing primitive values on scopes there were other ways to do this that were more efficient. I am trying to make this function less bloated.